Crash on Destroy Method: "View ... does not have a NavController set"
I am getting a crash in the onDestroy method with the following error:
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com..presentation.screens.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{dc9613c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2037 #7f0a05ae app:id/nav_container} does not have a NavController set
`


I am using a NavController  with bottom navigation. Here is my code for setting up the bottom navigation:
` val controller =
                bottomNav.setupWithNavController(
                    navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
                    fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
                    containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
                    intent = intent
                ) { selectedItem ->
                    onNavItemClicked(itemId = selectedItem.itemId)
                }`

My xml code
` <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />`

I get the crash when I open any bottom sheet, close it, and then open the next activity. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?
